# Codeigniter design architecture with vue.js

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js, architecture

I have an application already working with codeigniter and jquery. Both technologies with which I am very familiar.Recently my application has grown too much and my frontend has started to get a little disorganized, with very large files and difficult to maintain...In that time I started to study vue to implement in my project because it seems to work well with this concept of web components. My doubt is about merge the architectures that both frameworks (Vue and codeigniter) already have.

**This is the structure of a vue application.**

```
-  node_modules 
-  src
      components
      App.vue
      main.js
-  package.json
-  webpack.config.js
-  index.html
```

**And this is the codeigniter structure.**

```
- config
- controllers
- system
- models
- views
- node_modules
- index.php
```

**My idea is to create components in the vue to use them in my codeigniter views and my questions are:**

> What is the correct way to work with these architectures together?
>
> Where do I put the vue files? I thought about putting it in the codeginiter's **views** directory because it seemed more logical since the vue will work in the visualization layer but I don't know if this is correct.

i believe i'm a little confused because i'm just starting with vue :)

If anyone can help, I appreciate it! \o/